# knockout data binding with "with" or foreach?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I am very new to Knockout and trying to explore it. I know how to use foreach but confuse about "with". I just gone through the documentation of knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) for With. still like:

1) when should i used "with"

2) With is alternative for foreach?

3) is there any difference between "with" and foreach

Thanks in Advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) A **with** is a inline template binding, its commonly used when you want to hide a area when a sub ViewModel is null, its also good practice to use it when you want to change the context from the parent model to the sub model.

2) Not really, **with** works with any object. If your array can be null then **with** is good (I cant remember from top of my head if **foreach** binding works with null values)

3) Yes, they are totally different. **With** gives no array foreach template functionallity if you want to use **with** with a array then you need to use a **foreach** binding inside your **with**.

Also have a look at my Convention over configuration library, it takes away all headaches about bindings, here is a **with** example

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki/With-convention

edit: My library abstracts the **with** binding, the example in the above Github link would look like this without my convention library

```
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>

<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give a with example. In your Github link i cant see "with" example

Comment: after download only i find runner.html rest all the files are js. and i do not understand runner.html

Comment: All you need is the file under src, runner.html is just a file to run the unit tests. Include the src file and then your set, you can use the examples under the Github wiki to get you started